# ¿Es la siguiente frase enfática?

Tags: categorías-gramaticales, sintaxis

¿Es la forma de la siguiente frase enfática? Si no, ¿qué función cumple la inversión del sujeto?

> Ha destruido el fuego una gran cantidad de árboles.

Comment: No necesariamente. Solo pone el enfoque en la acción en vez del sujeto u objeto.

Comment: Si quieres dar la prioridad a la acción, mejor usa la forma pasiva: *una gran cantidad de árboles ha sido destruida.* — Ponerlo como tú dices, no enfatiza la acción, solamente el solo hecho de que quisiste informar primero la acción, no que muestres el énfasis ahí.

Comment: Gracias. Pensé lo mismo. Me topé con la oración en un ejercicio y la encontré bastante rara.

Comment: Para complementar: Si quisieras convertirla a una frase enfática, sería por ejemplo, "Lo que ha destruido una gran cantidad de árboles ha sido el fuego" ó "El fuego es lo que ha destruido una gran cantidad de árboles".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. No hace ningún énfasis adicional. La inversión del sujeto simplemente obedece a un tema de elegancia en el lenguaje, quizá un poco pedante.

Answer (score 0):

Además de no enfatizar nada, lo que hace es confundir porque, en este ejemplo concreto, tanto el sujeto como el objeto coinciden en número y persona, de forma que, tal y como está enunciada la frase del ejemplo y faltándonos el contexto y la lógica, podríamos plantearnos qué destruye qué exactamente.